# Could not load type 'System.Single[]&' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,

Tags: c#, visual-c++, mscorlib

From a `C#` project, we are making a call to a CLR based `VC++` method. We are passing an array of float values as out parameters.

We are getting the following error:

> Could not load type 'System.Single[]&' from assembly 'mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Earlier, both the C# and VC++ pojects were in 2010 and were working fine. We have migrated both of them to VS 2012, since then we are facing this issue.

What could be the reason?

C# Code:

```
float[] x = new float[401 * 3];
float[] y = new float[401 * 3];
Wrapper1.Compute(out x, out y);
```

VC++ CLR code:

```
static void Compute([Out] float (*x) __gc[],
 [Out] float (*y) __gc[])
 {

   ArgOutValueArray<float> arg_x(x, 401*3);

 }
```

The control is entering the Computer method in VC++, but getting the aforementioned exception during the declaration of the variable:

```
ArgOutValueArray<float> arg_x(x, 401*3);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the platform toolset of your C++ project (Project -> Properties -> General Tab)?

Comment: It's Visual Studio 2012 (v110)

Comment: Please, check if changing this value to *Visual Studio 2012 wxp* (**v110_xp**), the program still throws a exception.

Comment: Tried the wxp thing. Not able to compile the project.

Comment: The template class constructor is something like this:
 
ArgOutValueArray(T (__gc* __nogc& aRef) __gc[], CountRef cRef)